# Unable to issue a simple actionURL to access my handleActionRequest method. Really stumped

Tags: spring, controller, action, response, portlet

I've created a trivial Controller using Spring that extends AbstractController. 
All it does is issue a view that creates a simple form, and returns the actionURL 
so that the handleActionRequest method in my controller will be called.
I see the  value returned on the response in Fiddler.
But the handleActionRequest method is never reached.   Totally stumped.  Please help!!!

Here is the relevant piece of the portlet.xml

```
<portlet id="Source">
<description>Source</description>
<portlet-name>source</portlet-name>
<display-name>source</display-name>
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
<init-param>
    <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
    <value>/WEB-INF/source-portlet.xml</value>
</init-param>       
<supports>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>       
</supports>
<portlet-info>
            <title>Source</title>
            <short-title>Source</short-title>
            <keywords>source ibi</keywords>
</portlet-info>
<portlet-preferences>           
</portlet-preferences>
</portlet>
```

This is the ViewModeController the xml files refer to:

```
package com.ibi.bip.portlet;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;

import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.AbstractController;

import com.ibi.bip.portlet.ContactEvent;

public class ViewModeController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request,
            ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Entering ViewModeController.handleActionRequest");
        String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lName");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        ContactEvent contact = new ContactEvent(fName, lName, email);
        response.setEvent("hello", contact);
        request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("contact", contact);
        System.out.println("Exiting ViewModeController.handleActionRequest");
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,
            RenderResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Entering ViewModeController.handleRenderRequest");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("source");
        if (request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("contact") != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("contact", request.getPortletSession()
                    .getAttribute("contact"));
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting ViewModeController.handleRenderRequest");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

When run in Jetspeed, the handleRenderRequest successfully creates a form html from source.jsp that returns on the response the value of

this appears in Fiddler as

[protocol][host:port]/jetspeed/portlet/*ns:Ym9wczguMDo6c291cmNlfGQxfGY*/

But handleActionRequest() in ViewModeController (above) is never called. :(